# change a linux file to enconding type utf8 without converting characters

Tags: php, linux, encoding, utf-8

This problem is annoying me now! so thats why i am asking it here.
I know there is a lots of articles and topics about encoding but can't find the answer i need.

**Goal:**
I want to compare two mysql tables which contains fully identically fields and character sets.
The differences will be saved in a file and will be imported after the compare

**Way i do**
- MySQL PDO Connection is made with variable "set names utf8"
- Text is put via "file_put_content" to the file

**Problem:**
The type of the file with the differences is not utf8 and contains characters which are not the same as the source table.
Also after importing the file to the database it contains wrong characters in the table.

**Supposition:**
the source tables contains non utf8 characters. is this possible if the column is set to utf8?
and if that is true how can i convert those characters back to utf8?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the file? Prepending a simple '\xEF\BB\BF' to your text before calling file_put_contents should do.

Comment: Hi dbugxpert;  yes i tried this but its not working for me

Comment: Hi Moenie, can you give an example of your code? How do you check the file encoding type?

Comment: How do you define if your text is utf8? ascii is a subset of utf8 so if your data is ascii, `file` will detect it as such. file_put_contents does not check & set encoding for your file.

Please consider 

`file_put_contents("file.out", $data);`

vs

`file_put_contents("file.out", mb_convert_encoding("\xEF\xBB\xBF", 'UTF-8', 'auto').$data);`

Comment: its coming from MySQL database which has been set up has utf8

Comment: And why do you need to call `file` to determine the file type? What is the problem with the output? If your data is pure ascii, the file will be considered ascii,